# Not able to connect to JMX remotely for PocessBuilder program

Tags: java, spring, jmx, jconsole

We are getting problem in connecting through jmx via remote.we run a job through ProcessBuilder by program

## Code Snippet:

```
param ="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=A.B.C.D -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9875 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false "
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", param,"-cp", jobArtifact.getAbsolutePath());          
pb.command().add("org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner");
final Process process = processBuilder.start();
```

Process is being started but when we try to connect it with `jconsole` via remote it's not connecting... and connection failed message is coming:

```
Remote connection URL: service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://A.B.C.D:9875/jmxrmi
```

What we have tried:

1. Added `-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=A.B.C.D` and
   `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false`
2. `ProcessBuilder.getEnv()` and added our environment properties.
3. When we are running the same program via command prompt:

   ```
   java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9875 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -cp C:\jobs\abc.jar org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner
   ```

   it is running  and able to connect with `jmx` via remote with the same URL mentioned above.

Any suggestions/workaround would be welcome!!!

Comment: Try `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true`

Comment: Thanks Peter.I tried it but did not work for me.. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `-D` option needs to be a separate parameter to the `ProcessBuilder`:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java",
    "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote",
    "-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=A.B.C.D",
    // etc. etc.
    "-cp", jobArtifact.getAbsolutePath(),
    "org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner");
final Process process = processBuilder.start();
```

Your current code, with all of them concatenated together into one parameter, is essentially setting *one* property named `"com.sun.management.jmxremote -Djava.rmi.server.hostname"` to the value `"A.B.C.D -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9875 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false "` (including the trailing space).

Comment: Thanks Ian. I modified the code with paramters and added the parameter 

Now if print pb [java, -cp, c:\batch\jobs\autodata-imp-slave-example-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar, org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner, application-context.xml, sampleJob1, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl="false", -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote="true", -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port="9875", -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate="false"] but still JMX remote is disabled and not connect it to via remote.Moreover I can connect the same as local process.

Comment: @RishabhPandey Compare your version to mine - the `-D` options must be _before_ the class name `org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner` and must not have the surrounding quotes (it should be `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false`, not `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl="false"`)

Comment: Thanks Ian.I have added as you suggested just with little update in this order to put JVM arguments in command -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9875, 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
after setting in this order It worked for me.